# Developing with Rails on localhost:3000 in Windows VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to test our Rails app--served on `http://localhost:3000` -- in a Windows VM. I have read numerous articles out there about setting up my VM with shared networking, and opening ports on firewalls, and accessing through IE with the public IP address of the host machine. That all works...

What I want to know is if I can access my rails server (running on my host machine) on my guest machine using `http://localhost:3000` instead of `http://host-machine-ip-address:3000`.

My issue is that my app authenticates with OAuth & Facebook, and our development facebook account is set to use `http://localhost:3000`... so I can't use the host machine's IP address because I can't auth with Facebook in IE on my guest VM.

Is is possible to have the same server, running on the host machine, accessible by `http://localhost:3000` on ***BOTH*** the host machine and the guest VM?

My host machine is a Mac running 10.8.1, and I am virtualizing Windows 7 using VirtualBox (guest machine), for the purpose of cross-platform testing in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The simplest workaround would be to use something like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) on the Windows VM to tunnel `http://localhost:3000` (from the VM's perspective) to port 3000 on the physical machine, i.e. `http://host-machine-ip-address:3000`.